Are the p-values obtained on the same sample using synthetic AA tests (Monte Carlo) independent values?
Let's say we have the following procedure.
We take a fixed sample of size n and perform the procedure 1000 time:

we divide (split) it equally into 2 groups;
we calculate p value using the F function (for example, t test, but I am interested in the general case);
we got 1000 p value (or 1000 values of p value < alpha)

Are these 1000 values dependent or independent, given that we have all dealt with the same fixed sample and the same function F 1000 times?
UPD

i mean randomly divide (split) it equally into 2 groups.
AA tests mean controled experiment without difference between two groups (as opposed to AB tests).
synthetic tests means are artificial, simulated.


Despite having written an answer, by the way, I realise I don't have an idea what "synthetic AA tests" are (they don't feature in the question body), and it is generally good practice to explain all abbreviations. Never assume that abbreviations are the same in different subfields and cultures and that therefore everybody will know.

I assume what you mean is that you randomly split the data into two subsamples and then run a test that somehow compares the two subsamples.
There are two ways of interpreting this. Normally we would model the sample as randomly drawn from a probability model (often but not necessarily i.i.d.). In this case, a computed p-value gives information about the data and consequently one p-value is informative about another, so they are not independent.
Now you write that the data are "fixed", and what I wrote above models it as in fact random. If the data are fixed indeed (note that the term "sample" that you use for the data implicitly suggests that it was not fixed but rather random), and we have two independent random draws of pairs of subsamples, the p-values computed from them are indeed technically independent (also in the setup above if we talk about independence conditionally on the data). The difference in that case is that "a p-value gives information on the data" (as used as an argument for dependence above) in this case doesn't induce probabilistic dependence because the data are not probabilistic.
So the answer of your question depends on whether the data are treated as fixed or random. Which one is relevant depends on what you want to do with the 1000 p-values, and where the independence issue comes in.

in my case, the data is a metric of users for a period. For example, the revenue for March from users from Italy from 30 to 40 years old. I am concerned about the independence problem in the context of the fact that I want to calculate the confidence interval for the mean(p value < alpha) metric, where p value is a vector calculated according to the procedure mentioned in the text of the question. In total, I have 1000 0 or 1 and I want to calculate the confidence interval for the average using binomial proportion confidence int. It will be correct only if my 1000 observations are independent.

@РомановАндрей I don't really understand how "mean(p-value<alpha)" is a parameter for which you can compute a well defined confidence interval. Note that confidence intervals concern parameters of an assumed underlying distribution rather than statistics computed from the data (some statistics have a "population version", so I'm not saying what you want to do is impossible, but I can't comment on it because I'd need a proper formalisation of it with model assumptions, and be they nonparametric, in order to make sense of it).
